# Why can't I set a select option programmatically when using an object on a Reactive Form in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I'd like to figure out because I can't set the select option of a Reactive Form using the following typescript code:

**That's my class**

```
export class SlotStatusTypes {
    id: number;
    description: string;
}
```

**That's my component template**

```
<select id="subject" formControlName="subject" class="form-control"
   aria-describedby="subject">
   <option *ngFor="let statusType of slotStatusTypesList" [ngValue]="statusType">
      {{statusType.description}}
   </option>
</select>
```

**And that's in my component:**

```
slotStatusTypesList: SlotStatusTypes[] = [];
```

> The slotStatusTypesList variable is filled in by another HTTP GET call.

Here I initialize my form:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.slotForm = new FormGroup({
      ...
      subject: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required
      ]),
      ...
   });
}
```

Within a callback function is filled in the *slotForm* form among which the subject field after finding the value corresponding as you can see below:

```
let statusTypeFound: SlotStatusTypes = this.slotStatusTypesList.find(r => r.id === slotPlanning.statusTypeId);

this.slotForm.setValue({
   ...
   subject: statusTypeFound,
   ...
});
```

*Up to now it all works.*

Now, I want to set an identical object of type SlotStatusTypes in the *slotForm* form instead of looking for an object by a list, see below:

```
let slotStatusType: SlotStatusTypes = {
   id: slotPlanning.id, //id: 1
   description: slotPlanning.description //description: "Available"
};

this.slotForm.setValue({
   ...
   subject: slotStatusType,
   ...
});
```

At this point the *slotForm* form select isn't set with the selected value as I expected.

Why doesn't it work in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your problem is here, when creating new `slotStatusType` object.

```
let slotStatusType: SlotStatusTypes = {
   id: slotPlanning.id,
   description: slotPlanning.description
};
```

It is a new object with a new reference, that does not exists in `slotStatusTypesList` array. So `select` cannot match any item in the list with `slotStatusType`, although properties `id` and `description` are the same.

To `setValue` of `FormControl` you need to use item from `slotStatusTypesList` array. I am not sure if you can avoid searching for it, but you can optimize your code to save a reference of an item once you find it.

Comment: Hi mimo, I explain better, the slotStatusType object is only an custom object what I need. I can try to pass an object like this `let slotStatusType: SlotStatusTypes = { id: 1, description: "Available" };` but it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: I understand, what you are trying to do, but every time you create new object by `{...}` you are creating "fresh" object with a new reference. Since you initialize dropdown with objects from an array, `select` cannot match your "fresh" object reference to any of its options.

Comment: So, how can I set the select input without using `slotStatusTypesList`?

Comment: You cannot. To select item in your input you need to use item from `slotStatusTypesList`, because the value you assign into your input have `===` value in your option.

Comment: Optionally you can use instead of `[ngValue]="statusType"` following `[ngValue]="statusType.description"` in your option. Then you would be able to select something programmatically without iterating list. Strings are primitive types, thus they are not compared by reference.

Comment: Surely I can resolve it with an attribute. It was only a my doubt for that specific case. Thanks Mimo.